# Backbone Marionette architecture, sub Application

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Please help me with Backbone.Marionette architecture.
For example we have the site with difference sections, like list with products, product, search page.
And all this sections have several Layouts, with many Regions and logic.

In this case we should create one general Marionette Application and several sub Application for each section.
General Application should track router and starting/stoping necessary sub Application?
Is that correct, or we should choose some other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) is have the sub-applciations start automatically with the main app, and each sub-application is responsible for its own routing.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/contacts_app.js